# What is the difference between \d+ and \d- OR \w+ and \w- in regular expression terms?

Tags: python, regex

As per title, what is the difference between:

`\d+` and `\d-` 
`\w+` and `\w-`

in regular expression terms? What influence has `+` and `-` ?

Comment: `-` only has significance if used in a character class when identifying a range, as in `[a-z]`, otherwise it carries its literal meaning.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`\d+` means one or more digit `[0-9]` (depending on LOCALE)
`\d-` means a digit followed by a dash `-`

`\w+` means one or more word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (depending on LOCALE)
`\w-` means a word char followed by a dash `-`

Comment: `\w` includes numerics `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  The exact range can be adjusted by flags ASCII and LOCALE.

Comment: @M42 the same goes for `\d`, it might also match hindu-arabic digits